# TLS Version on Titanium Webview

Tags: android, webview, titanium, titanium-mobile, tls1.2

I have been trying to load an URL on a `Titanium.UI.WebView`. This URL directs to a payment gateway and supports only `TLSv1.1` or higher. While the page loads without issue on iOS and Android 5.0 onwards, it does not on Android versions 4.1 to 4.4.

> var webview =
>   Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'http://www.sampleurl.com'});

Upon research, it has been identified that even though `TLSv1.1 and v1.2` is supported on Android 4.1 to 4.4, it has been disabled by default. Although, I'm unable to find a way to enable it on `Titanium SDK` 3.5.1 and 4.0.0.

Is there any way to specify the TLS version when loading a URL on a `Titanium.UI.WebView`? or is there any other possible workaround for this issue?